# Bash: Choose row with the highest value in specified column in multiple files and create one output file with rows containing the max

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have a directory with files of similar names like the following

```
mi001
mi002
...
mi034
...
```

What I would like to do is find the highest value in column 14. Then I would like to append the entire row with the highest value to an output file. As a final result, I would like one output file with the highest row from every original file.

sample file

| c1 | c2 | ... | c14 | c15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | ... | 5 | 0.5 |
| 2 | t | ... | 4 | 0.9 |

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Does column 14 contain numbers or letters or both?  Some example of the file?

Comment: column 14 contains only numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method will just sort the files and pick up the last line from each file.  For example,

```
for file in mi*
do
    sort +13 -n $file | tail -1
done > result
```

`+13` sorts on 14th column, `-n` makes sure it sorts on numeric order.

If `+13` does not work, you can replace the sort statement with

```
sort -k14,14 -n $file | tail -1
```

Comment: This gives me the error `sort: cannot read: +13: No such file or directory`

Comment: I tested it on an Ubuntu Linux box.  What is your platform?  You just need to find out the switch for sorting on 14th column.

Comment: @unxnut keys might work better :`-k14,14`

Comment: Thanks @FelixJN, I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Following the sparse information you provide, `awk` would work like this (assuming space or tab separated fields *and header in 1st line*):

```
awk 'NR == 2 {totmax=$14 ; maxline=$0 ; filemax[FILENAME]=$14 ; fileline[FILENAME]=$0}
     FNR>1 && $14 > totmax {maxline=$14; totmax=$14}
     FNR>1 && ($14 > filemax[FILENAME] || !filemax[FILENAME]) {filemax[FILENAME]=$14 ; fileline[FILENAME]=$0 }
     END {print "line with total maximum:\n"maxline
          print "maximums for files:"
          for (file in filemax) {print file":",fileline[file]}}' mi*
```

Comment: this prints out `lines with total maximum:` and then all of the column names. On a new line `maximums for files` then one line for each file with the name of the file and the name of column 14. `mi001: col14`. It does not give me the maximum values. Additionally, as stated, I would like the entire row containing the maximum values and not just the max values.

Comment: @keenan well, you didn't mention headers originally. Corrected for both